# Controller not hitting Delete method in WebApi

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webapi

I have an issue with Delete Method in WebApi. It's not hitting from controller.
This is a Web Api Code having attribute routing and Get and Delete Method accepting same parameter.
When debugger goes to controller it does not go from DeleteAsync() to Delete Method in Web Api.
**WebApi Code:**

```
        [Route("api/Products/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            List<ProductModel> showProductById = dbOperations.ShowProductById(id);
            return Ok(showProductById);
        }
        
        [Route("api/Products/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            int rowId = dbOperations.DeleteProduct(id);
            return Ok(rowId);
        }
```

**Controller Code:**

```
 public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
        {
            productApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"]);
            var response = productApiClient.DeleteAsync("Products/" + id).Result;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Comment: By default controller methods are for HTTP GETs. Add an `[HttpDelete]` attribute to the Delete method.

Comment: Yes, I used that also but not worked. After I executed the web api on fiddler and it showing "Method" Not Allowed. Then I change some codes in webconfig and it worked. Codes-   <system.webServer>
   <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
   </modules>
    <handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV"/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark what HTTP verb can be used to access that methods. You can do this by setting the corresponding attribute:

```
[HttpGet("api/Products/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
...


[HttpDelete("api/Products/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
...
```

Edit: using AspNetCore Version 5.0.0

Comment: Showing Error HttpDeleteAttribute does not contain a contructor that takes 1 arguments. By the way issue has been resolved by adding some lines of code in web.config file.